# Navbar dropdown menu not working in Bootstrap 3.1.0

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Question:**

I'm doing some jquery on the dropdown menu of bootstrap; i'm making it to animate by clicking it but i saw a problem.

**Problem occurred:**

After replacing `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave` to `.click`, when you open the dropdown nothing shows up.

**Cause of Problem:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//The problem occurred at the two functions below
    $(".dropdown").click(function () {
        $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideDown();
    }).click(function () {
        $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideUp();
    });
});
```

**Clarification:** 
Go here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jakobaindreas11/xdMLQ/embedded/result/) and click the two dropdowns and nothing shows up. Only a thin slice shows up

**Answering Helpers**

Here's the fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakobaindreas11/xdMLQ/)

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown").click(function () {
        $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideDown();
    }).click(function () {
        $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideUp();
    });
});
```

Any help will be a great solution